# .htacces redirect from example.com/abc to https://www.example.com/abc

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, amazon-web-services

**htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Above code I'm using in my `.htaccess` and Now I want to redirect when someone type `example.com/abc` to `https://www.example.com/abc`.

By using the above code when I goto `example.com/abc` its showing `404` error.

So please someone help me to solve this. Answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Do I want to remove any line from the existing line before adding your code?

Comment: you sure install an SSL on domain

Comment: yeah I have ssl on my domain